# Are there infinitely many $k$ for which $\frac{\sigma(k)}{k}=n^p$ and $p$ is an odd prime?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, divisors-multiples, elementary-proofs

I would like to know if there are infinitely many $k$ for which $$\sigma(k)/k=n^p$$ such that $m=k{n}^{p-1}$ with $m,n>0$ and $p$ is an odd prime?

Note: $\sigma(\frac{m}{{n}^{p-1}})$ is the sum of divisors function of $\frac{m}{ {n}^{p-1}}$ such that $m=k{n}^{p-1}$.

**Edit 2**: I edited the question as it has the same meaning for the precedent.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It is trivial that $\sigma(k)>k$ for any $k>1$, since $1$ and $k$ are two distinct divisors of $k$. Hence your equation is only satified when $m=n=1$. At any rate, this question is not of research level, voting to close.

Comment: @GHfromMO, thank you for your comments and i didn't get attention for no solution existed for sigma(k)=k for all k\geq 1

Comment: I suggest that you delete this question.

Comment: but i edited it

Comment: With the notation $m=kn$ your new equation becomes $\sigma(k)/k=n^2$. Hence it would be more natural to ask if there are infinitely many $k$'s for which $\sigma(k)/k$ is a square.

Comment: yes and this what i meant

Comment: BTW there should be infinitely many $k$, such as $51590^2$,
for which both $k$ and $\sigma(k)$ are square, and thus
$\sigma(k)/k$ is a *rational* square.  Perhaps this already
follows from known results.

Comment: @Noam, "Numbers $n$ such that sum of divisors of $n^2$ is a square" is http://oeis.org/A008847 which has a reference to a preprint of Kaplansky. I can't find the Kaplansky work anywhere, so I don't know whether he proved anything in it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, i edited the question beacause it is on hold , I have tried to generalise it , pleas check the question again

Comment: I checked it. It's still not terribly interesting (to me). Noam's question is more interesting.

Comment: @Noam, sent you the relevant page from the preprint of Kaplansky that Gerry mentions.

Comment: @Gerry, also sent the one page from Kap's preprint to Noam

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question can be reformulated as:

> **Question.** Are there infinitely many $k$'s such that $\sigma(k)/k$ is a square?

If the answer is yes, then (trivially) there are infinitely many [multiperfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply_perfect_number). This consequence is not known unconditionally, so at the moment we cannot prove that the answer is yes.

If the answer is no, then it implies that each perfect number is divisible by a prime from a fixed finite set of primes, because the product of two coprime perfect numbers satisfies $\sigma(k)/k=4$. This consequence is not known unconditionally, so at the moment we cannot prove that the answer is no.

In short, it seems that above question is out of reach at the moment.

Comment: thank you for your answer, if it was asked before ,could you give me a paper or .. ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: I don't think it was asked before, but I am not familiar with the literature of multiperfect numbers.

Comment: According to your answer it's seems that the question is hard for proof and interesting , i don't know why no vote for this question ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik, hard, yes; interesting, that's in the eye of the beholder. In two short paragraphs, GH has reduced it to some well-known hopeless problems. There is no difficulty in Number Theory in tweaking well-known hard problems to come up with any number of further hard problems.

Comment: @GerryMyerson,thank you very much for this observation.

Comment: @GHfromMO, i edited the question  may now it's seems important for this case where the power are prime .

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: My answer applies almost verbatim for your new question: if $k$ is the product of $p$ pairwise coprime perfect numbers, then $\sigma(k)/k=2^p$. Also, please do not edit questions for which there is an accepted answer. Instead, open a new question.

Comment: GH, do you have any opinion on Noam's variant, $\sigma(x^2) = y^2?$ Noam suggests infinitely many solutions. Gerry wrote me to ask for the Kaplansky preprint mentioned at the OEIS page, Kap (and Dickson, pages 54-58 in volume I of his History) credit the problem to Ozanam. Kap found a way to make a group out of squarefree soluitons $x,$ which increases the number of solutions that one may find but does not appear to make it infinite

Comment: @WillJagy: I don't have an opinion as I haven't thought about it. Maybe later, but at the moment I am busy with other things. Also, I am not too familiar with this type of problems.